# What makes JSFiddle secure from XSS based attacks?

Tags: javascript, security, xss, jsfiddle

I am curious, what makes [www.jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net) secure from XSS based attacks? They have a support for accounts so clearly any script they run on the browser may do evil things.

Comment: The code is actually running in an iframe so it can't directly take access of the parent.

Comment: Ah, so it runs within an iframe which has a different Origin? Is that all? Make it an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you look at the results pane for a fiddle you'll notice that it's actually an IFRAME pointing to a different domain which means that built in security will kick in which generally prevents access to the parent window.

This fiddle for example : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/y9zCK/

Is actually served by : http://fiddle.jshell.net/jomanlk/y9zCK/show/

Comment: I'd like to add that you can login at http://fiddle.jshell.net/. This could be abused by hackers redirecting to that page, asking the user to login and then spy the session id.

Comment: How could you fully prevent this sort of hacking on jsfiddle?