# JSFiddle error: Please use POST request - after NoScript's XSS warning

Tags: firefox-addon, xss, jsfiddle

When I press Run button on JSFiddle, sometimes my NoScript addon will display an XSS warning and the fiddle shows this message instead of my changes:

```
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

I allowed scripts from all domains that jsfiddle uses. I also created an Anti-XSS Protection Exception, but this didn't help:

```
^http?://fiddle\.net/
```

How can I get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JSFiddle uses http://fiddle.jshell.net/ server for displaying results (see [What makes JSFiddle secure from XSS based attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6732501/1176601)).

So the rule should be like this:

```
^https?://fiddle\.jshell\.net/_display
```

Source: http://curiousx.wordpress.com/2011/11/28/jsfiddle-error-please-use-post-request/

---

**Update**: FTR, for the embeded stackoverflow code snippets, the rule should be:

```
^https?://stacksnippets\.net/js
```